# Getting value from remote database and posting it to hyperlink in android?

Tags: android

In my project I am getting the employee id values and employee names from the database. I am displaying the **names of employees** in **listview**. When I click on the name(here the name textview is a hyperlink) in the listview all the details of that particular employee will be displayed. Based on the **employee id** when we click on the name that employee details should display. Please help me how to do this in android.

For ex: In general we give like this ----http://sample.com?id=1
 How to do that in android?

Comment: So I'm a bit confused by what you're asking exactly. You're already able to connect to the database and get the employee names to populate the ListView and just need to know how to append the employee id to the String " http://sample.com?id= "?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Actualy what requirement of mine is displaying employee's names and once employee name is clicked then in another page cllicked employee's details has to displayed.Here I am able to displaye employee names.But I am unable to displayed clicked employee's details.Could you explain how can i retrieve details of the particulate clicked employee name baseed on either id or name.Here I am retrieving name and id of the employees list.How can I do this in andriod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your question and follow-up comment, what you're gonna want to do is as follows:

1. Grab the employee name and id as you have already done.
2. Make an Object that will hold both the employee name and id. Make a toString() method that will return the employee name as a String. The reason for this is because when the ListView is inflated, it defaults to calling the toString() method of its objects (each list entry). Make sure to also have a way to get the employee id from the Object via either a public getter or making the id a public variable itself.
3. Make the ListView's ArrayList use this Object and set it accordingly.
4. Then you must use [onItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) to query the site you were referencing in your question. However, when you do query this site, make sure to concatenate the employee id to the end of the URL. Do what you will once you query the site.